# SharePoint 2010 app server is responding slowly?

Tags: managed-metadata, performance, service-application

SharePoint 2010 application server responds slowly, below are observed from the ULS during the slowness

1. Timer Job SchedulingUnpublish
2. MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting.
3. Timer Job job-site-inventory-usage-collection
4. SPCertificateValidator.Validate

any suggestion, what could have caused this slowness?

**Update:**

1. All most 20% of the requests takes more than 10sec on the application server whereas it takes ~2sec on the WFEs.
2. Average CPU usage on the server is - ~5%
3. Average Memory availability is - ~24GB
4. Network usage is far below when compare to other WFEs.
5. Number of SQL connection is less than : 50% (when compare to other WFEs)
6. Any critical timer jobs were during that period : No (except the web analytics timer job runs early in the morning)
7. Any critical error is reported on the ULS: No
8. Any critical error is reported on the Event viewer : No

Web Analytics Service Application is running on the server and Deadlock is reported in every 20mins - Deadlock happened in “WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_StagingDB”, does it cause the performance issue on the application server...?

**Update2:**

> 06/13/2012 12:53:00.39 w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (**SPCertificateValidator.Validate). Execution
>   Time=34323.7428220626 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87**
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:00.45   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#2). Execution
>   Time=18.354288044989  e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:00.59   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#3). Execution
>   Time=34.8552679181293 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:00.70   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#4). Execution
>   Time=35.8224299457054 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:00.78   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#5). Execution
>   Time=23.6669744339015 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:00.86   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#6). Execution
>   Time=30.4695149802559 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:01.01   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#7). Execution
>   Time=50.7561715245932 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:01.08   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#8). Execution
>   Time=14.7700336215916 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:01.19   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData#9). Execution
>   Time=44.1885770398193 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:01.23   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint Server
>   Search    Query   dn2n    High    Exception in
>   SearchBoxEx::OnLoad:System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was
>   being aborted.     at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()     at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)     at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.End()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.WebPartLoc.StopProcessingRequestIfNotNeeded()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.WebPartLoc.OnLoad(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx.OnLoad(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)  e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87
>   
> 06/13/2012 12:53:01.23   w3wp.exe (0x06A0)   0x1A44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (GET:http://mywebapp/testpage.aspx)). Execution
>   Time=35308.3894740812 e7c88374-2bfe-4cf1-977f-5eb23670ed87

Comment: It could be almost anything.  Utilization may be low, but what is the error rate on your network interfaces (dropped packets, etc).  Use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to watch the traffic and see, are requests staying for the server, or is the server making multiple requests back to the client during this period?  Do you have antivirus running on the server or a host based security product (especially anything that may have an NDIS driver installed), check those logs.  If you have other servers, move the service applications to them and see how the server responds.

Answer (score 1):

This seems somehow related to a know issue with search that triggers a delay in the Validate() method. 
The following is taken from Microsoft:

> **Sympthom**: Search results always come back quite slowly the very first time you do a search in FAST Search Center after a prolonged period of user inactivity. All subsequent searches come back quickly and at an acceptable level.  Please note that this issue is not specific to FAST, the same behavior exists with
>   SharePoint Server 2010 and using the Enterprise Search Center.
>
> **Cause**: Typically, this is caused by the amount of time used by SPCertificateValidator.Validate() method, whose role is to check the validity of the certificate used to encrypt communications with the Security Token Service(STS). ***CUT...*** If SPCertificateValidator.Validate() takes a long time, you should be able to see that either in ULS logs:
>
> *w3wp.exe SharePoint Foundation Monitoring b4ly High Leaving Monitored Scope (SPCertificateValidator.Validate). Execution Time=15064.2596346328*

Here is the link to the original kb article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2639348. See if the provided solution resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting your infrastructure guys to set up some performance monitoring and tracing on the server(s) that is having the issue to see where bottlenecks are.

Some questions that need to be asked are:

1. Are all pages slow? or only some? Is slow during a specific period?
2. What are the slow pages doing? i.e. communicate with SQL DBs? Load Data from a external data source?
3. Are the application server hosted via different zones. (Intranet and Extranet)?
4. Is there any crawls or other things running in the background?
5. Are there a lot of load? (Do you have the right specs on the server to handle these load?).
6. Are the servers load balance (assuming not a standalone environment).

I can go on and on but that's my two cent.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth mentioning turning on the developer dashboard if you believe that individual load times are high it will break it down.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/patrick_heyde/archive/2009/11/16/sharepoint-2010-enable-using-developer-dashboard.aspx